# How can I setup a CentOS login domain on our local network?

Tags: centos, networking, login, domain

I'm looking to create some sort of local domain for my office [ON THE LOCAL NETWORK] - all our machines run CentOS7 and I would like to startup a machine, see my name, then log-in, add something to my desktop, do some work, log off. Then use another computer and see the same name, I login, find all my documents, desktop etc. there. A bit like a work login that works for all computers on side. If anyone knows how to make this happen, your answer would be much appreciated, especially if it can communicate with Windows and work that way too, but that isn't needed.

Example on machine 1:

enter username: myusername
enter password: mypassword

"Logging in NAME" - logs in, I can use the computer to work on/save files.

Then on machine 2 later on:

enter username: myusername
enter password: mypassword

"Logging in NAME" - (recognising my account the same as the other machines on site), then can access the files I saved to my desktop on my desktop now and carry on with work....

Just some kind of local network domain that many schools, offices etc. use - even some sort of management hosting application that works over a local network.

Thanks, Oliver

[Screenshots for @jsbillings have been removed by @ORICKETTS]

Comment: ... how do you want the files to be shared? Sync them to the local machine on login, or keep everything on a network share that's being mounted?

Comment: @Panki How can I sync them to the local machine on login - I currently have a network share accessed through my CentOS file explorer at the path: smb://ipaddress/sharedfolder

Comment: @Panki - good idea actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For account management, you can use [FreeIPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeIPA), which will create a centralized identity management platform.  It uses LDAP for managing the user account information and access, and kerberos to authenticate users.  It is similar to Active Directory in that you have a central location for managing users, and single-signon enabled for the entire realm.  There's even some configuration you can define in LDAP that CentOS systems can use, such as sudo access.

Once you have identity mangement set up, you can set up a shared home directory network storage service.  The easiest is to use [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).  With NFSv4 and Kerberos from the FreeIPA service, you can secure NFS.

Comment: I'm having a look at the download instructions on FreeIPA's website: [link](https://access.redhat.com/products/identity-management#getstarted) for CentOS7, but if you look at that link, I need to know if I should download and install an IdM Server or Client - I also have an NFS setup with a windows share that works with CentOS and I also have the option for a network drive from my router. - Also, is FreeIPA and their NFS system all 100% FREE? Many Thanks for your help

Comment: - and @jsbillings where it says 'STEP 2' - set a servername - server.example.com - what do I do there? - Do I have to have a domain purchased or just make one up. If the link didn't work before. This is the page I'm discussing: [CLICK HERE](https://access.redhat.com/products/identity-management#server)

Comment: @ORICKETTS yes, FreeIPA is free, and the built in NFS server in CentOS is too.  Red Hat packages up FreeIPA and some other tools into a commercial product, but all the components are free in CentOS, you just need to set them up yourself.  You can get a domain, or just make one up, just know that DNS has to be correct for everything, so you might need to run your own DNS server too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply - I still don't quite follow, does it need a seperate machine to host it or can I just install on my CentOS7 machine and it will work for the rest of the machines on the network? The server/client thing? - Do I setup the server on the hosting one (my machine) (also does that have to be constantly on) - and setup as client on the other machines one by one? - So I could setup and make up a domain for free? DNS server? - sorry, I did mention I'm really inexperienced, could you explain. - Thanks so much

Comment: It's going to be a problem if the 'server' machine that the IPA server is downloaded/installed to has to be on all the time - if I could get my hands on a [virtual machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589350/how-can-i-get-my-hands-on-a-free-virtual-machine-and-how-does-virtualbox-work) - could I host from there? [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589350/how-can-i-get-my-hands-on-a-free-virtual-machine-and-how-does-virtualbox-work)

Comment: @ORICKETTS yes this would need to be a server that all of the other computers talk to. Ideally, you’d have three servers, for redundancy.

Comment: I noticed in another question that you’re using samba against active directory. You can use AD in Linux for authenticating and authorization, so you don’t need to set up a separate authentication service. Just so you know.

Comment: I have tried to setup and it says an error has occured with my hostname when I try to setup - it first says configure my hostname with this command: [root@server ~]# hostnamectl set-hostname server.example.com - and you said I can make something up for the hostname (my computer name is d1) (if that makes a difference?) - and then later on in the process when I use the command: ipa-server-install - it asks me for the hostname address again and I enter it and it says error occured with it. Do you know why this would happen? I'll add some screenshots to my original question.

Comment: see added images on the original question, view them in the order 2,1,3

Comment: It needs to be a name it can reach. Either use a real host name or add it to your local dns or /etc/hosts

Comment: How do I know what my real hostname is? If I do the command 'Hostname'- the output is 'd1' but it needs to be in the form example.example.com - I'll have a look at the file and see if I can add something to it or use one from there. Thanks

Comment: It still says 'needs to be fully qualified' - I looked in the logs and in /etc/hosts and it just says localhost.localdomain and it won't allow that - what do I do!!!?

Comment: For IPA, DNS has to be correct, so putting the IP address and FQDN to /etc/hosts is really just a workaround until you've got local DNS set up with the correct hostnames.  IPA and its components are complicated things and it might be better if you used AD for this instead.

Comment: I've tried to add the one I'm using to that file and I still get that error @jsbillings??