# How can I get my hands on a free virtual machine and how does VirtualBox work?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like a virtual machine and lots of places online are saying that the website VirtualBox supplies free virtual machines, I go to their [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and just see a download button? - I want to have a virtual machine accessable from my CentOS7 machine. - Can anyone help? Thanks

(EDIT) - I also wondered if VirtualBox's virtual machine's operating system can be chosen - because another CentOS one or Windows would be fine.

Comment: This sounds like a misunderstanding: Virtualbox does NOT offer free hosting of virutal machines. It "merely" is a program that allows you to run virtual machines on a server you will have to provide (this can be your PC, too). The guest system (or systems - you can run several, as long as the host hardware can bear it) can be choosen freely, but again the installation files fore the (guest) operating system have to be provided by you.

Comment: If you already have CentOS running, you can use the included hypervisor, libvirtd/kvm, to run virtual machines. It will work better than virtualbox for running Linux VMs.

Comment: @Fiximan Thanks, if they only offer the program to allow you to run them, you said I have to provide a server - how can I do that and how can I get a virtual machine running even if I host it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox is a free program available for multiple operating systems which allows you to create as many virtual machines as you like (and have capacity for), using whichever operating system you like (so long as it's compatible with the emulated hardware).  They do not, however, provide operating systems or licenses for them.

If you want to run a virtualized CentOS system, you will need to download a CentOS installation medium (typically an ISO image), and "insert" that into the virtual optical drive.

Explaining in more detail how to use VirtualBox in specific, or virtual machines in the abstract, is beyond the scope of this SE site.

Comment: You could grab one of the Vagrant images if you don’t want to install from the install medium. https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=virtualbox&q=CentOS

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks